# How to add autolayout constraints to a multi-line UILabel inside tableview headerView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I have searched all day for a solution to this problem. I am trying to have my UILabels autosize themselves based on the length of the text inside a `tableViewHeaderView`. Normally, with my UILabels inside a UIView, I would set top, leading, and trailing constraints to the UILabel and it would work just like how I wanted. However, I can't get that working inside a `tableViewHeaderView`. I am able to set top and leading constraints but my trailing constraint doesnt seem to be working. The text goes beyond the width of the screen.

Setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property to a number solves the issue but I don't want to have to hard code that.

Correct me if I am wrong, but setting the leading and trailing constraints should be able to give me the width of the view does it not? Then I could set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` with that value. But that value is 2403 which is way longer than the width of the screen.

Anyone else experience this?

```
#import "CustomTableViewHeader.h"

@implementation ReplyHeader{
    UILabel *questionLabel;
}



questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
            questionLabel.text = @"SAMPLE TEXT: I had a question about how I can be a better human being using your method. I belive it is an integral part of what it means to be a human so I want to learn more if you are able give more details about it. I also found that what you said about the dogs out there is very cool and would love to learn more about that.";
            questionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:17];
        questionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        questionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        questionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self addSubview:questionLabel];
```

Constraints

```
  [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:questionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f]];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:questionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f]];

            [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:questionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:10]];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:questionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:-10]];
```

update view

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = questionLabel.frame.size.width;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Are you adding `questionLabel` inside `awakeFromNib`? And where are you adding constraints? And what are your constraints for the `UITableView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView's do not get along with AutoLayout. Both header and footer have inherit that problem.
As you might already know, UITableViews are fancy UIScrollViews. If you have ever tried to work with a scroll view, lots of elements and AutoLayout you must know that it does not work well. It lags. That's why UITableView reuse cells. It improves performance and they do not use AutoLayout.

You should try something like

```
 // with this you will get the most compressed size for your view if the constraints properly define it's size
 CGFloat height = [footer systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
 footer = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(footer.frame), CGRectGetWidth(footer.bounds), height);
 // This will tell the layout engine to ignore the view and not try to resize it
 view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone; 
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer;
```